# How to update xml file without using Linq?

Tags: c#, xml

I have this xml file:

```
<students>
<student>
    <name>Mark</name>
    <age>20</age>
</student>
<student>
    <name>Adam</name>
    <age>32</age>
</student>
```

I want to change the age of Adam, for that I did:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("/path/to/sutdents.xml");
XmlNode n = doc.SelectSingleNode("/students/student[name='" + student.name + 
"']");
if (n != null)
{
   n.SelectNodes("age").Item(0).FirstChild.Value = new_value;
}
```

but I get "n" as a null value.
I tried another way to do that by searching for the node using foreach and make change, but I get Null Exception:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("/path/to/sutdents.xml");
XmlNodeList nodes = doc.SelectNodes("/students/student");
foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
 {
   if (node.FirstChild.InnerText == student.name)
    {
     node.SelectSingleNode("age").InnerText = new_value;
    }
  }
```

what I missing here please?
Thanks in advance

Comment: `name` is not an attribute of `student`, but a descendant. IIRC, the [key='value'] syntax looks for attribute values. your second attempt looks right, but you should make sure you start in students, and not at the document root.

Comment: so how can I fixe that please?

Comment: how are you going from `doc` to `nodes` in the second example? probably needs to be something like `var nodes = doc.SelectNodes("student")`

Comment: Deserialize into List<Student> - loop until ADAM is found. Change Age=xx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Code is Correct here is a screen shot of your debugged code with same xml and mentioned code, check you are passing student.name with correct value and case sensitive.

[image]

Comment: as you say I had a problem with student.name ... Thank you

Comment: why removed the solution flag?

Comment: It's not me! I add it now

Comment: you can mark up many , but every question have max 1 solution :)

Comment: I should have 15 reputaions... can you do it please forHussein Golshani?

Comment: Updated his answer

Answer (score 1):

i hope this helps;

When Using **foreach**:

```
 XmlNodeList studentsList = doc.ChildNodes[0].SelectNodes("student");

foreach (XmlNode node in studentsList)
{
  if (node.ChildNodes[0].InnerText == student.name) //name
   {
      node.ChildNodes[1].InnerText = new_value; //age
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to run your code. that is work! check what is the value of `student.name`.

XML [sutdents.xml]

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<students>
  <student>
    <name>Mark</name>
    <age>20</age>
  </student>
  <student>
    <name>Adam</name>
    <age>32</age>
  </student>
</students>
```

sample code:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("sutdents.xml");
XmlNode n = doc.SelectSingleNode("/students/student[name='Adam']");
if (n != null)
{
    n.SelectNodes("age").Item(0).FirstChild.Value = "44";
}
doc.Save("sutdents.xml");
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this using XDocument:

```
private static void UpdateXML(string xmlpath, string studentName, int age)
{
    var doc = XDocument.Load(xmlpath);

    //Get student
    var student = doc.Descendants("student").Where(att => att.Element("name") != null && att.Element("name").Value.Equals(studentName)).FirstOrDefault();
    if (student != null)
        student.Element("age").Value = age.ToString();
    doc.Save(xmlpath);
}
```

Comment: OP doesn't want to use Linq.

Comment: My bad, I didn't realized that :(